# Xamarin update silently fails

Tags: xamarin, installation, xamarin-studio, failed-installation

[Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 3, Windows 10 Pro v1703 x64, Xamarin 4.4.0.34]

I am trying to update Xamarin & related components inside VS. (**Tools -> Options... -> Xamarin -> Other -> Check Now**). The 3 updates (Xamarin 4.6.0.299, Xamarin Profiler 1.5.5, Xamarin iOS Simulator 1.1.1.1) have downloaded and are all labeled **Download completed. Pending to install.**

However, when I click the Install button, the Xamarin Updates dialog closes and nothing else happens. I have rebooted, done a repair of VS 2015, but no luck.

Is there an error log file I can look at for more info? Where are these installers saved that I could delete them and try to start over? Thanks for any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to cobble together some links from various places - there's a decent chance "similar" links will be available in the future? I installed manually and VS seems to be happy.

http://download.xamarin.com/XamarinforVisualStudio/Windows/Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.6.0.299.msi

https://dl.xamarin.com/profiler/profiler-windows.msi

https://dl.xamarin.com/xamarin-simulator/Xamarin.Simulator.Installer.1.1.1.1.msi

Also, the installers are downloaded to the temp folder `\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\MonoDevelop-4.0\Cache\TempDownload\` (mine had 8GB - good to clear out!)